# VS 2008 "Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have VS 2005 and VS 2008 installed side by side. It is interesting that I can use development server under VS 2005. But when I tried in VS 2008, it gave me an error "Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server".

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking the port configuration of VS 2008?
If it's not set to automatic it may be using a port that is in use?
If it is set to auto-assign then try specifying a port and picking one which you know to be free.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. But how can I do that. I cannot find it from project - > Property.

Comment: its under the web tab of the project properties

Comment: not sure if we have the same version. :=) Under Web site project Property pages, I only see Reference, Build, Accessibility, Start Options and Msbuild Options. I guess it is the Start options you mean right? I cannot change option, unless I need to use custom server, (IIS)? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the  `WebDev.WebServer.exe.manifest` file with new working one or good working copy which is in the location:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\
```

Then restart.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a website and not a web project then you can set the port properties from the property window.
Select the project from the solution explorer then press (ctrl+w then p) to bring up the property window.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it work by reinstalling VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the port developmentserver will use directly in your solution file. Simply edit the VWDPort property in the ProjectSection of the web project entry.
First call netstat in your command line to chek if the current port is already in use.
That did it for me.